# Can I access properties of a ListViewItem.Tag rather than just the "ToString" method?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, inheritance

Be patient, not sure how best to ask this one ...

1. I have a listView Control on a Windows Form and I add items to it that are the names of the text files in a certain directory.
2. each of those files is loaded as an object "ResultFile" and is assigned many properties based on text within - "string Type", "int NumberOfLines", "bool IsGeneric" etc.
3. A user can select/deselect freely but I would like to make decisions based on the text file type they have selected already.  As a rough idea, if they have already selected one where "Type=="x1" I don't want them to be able to select another one.  If they select 2 or more where the IsGeneric==true, I want to give them a warning ...

I started by extending the ListViewItem with this

```
public class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLines { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeneric { get; set; }

    public MyListViewItem(string s)
        : base(s)
    { }
}
```

I was happy with this as it was the first time I've extended a control (yes, I'm new to this) ... This allows me to add my own types of "ListViewItems" and I can access the properties to make decisions but I found the "tag" property and thought I could just tie my object to it and access they items directly. I looked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag.aspx) and it said I can attach "ANY" object but I don't know how to use it.

I don't seem to be able to do anything except access the default object methods.

```
     myListView.Item[1].Tag.ToString();
```

Seems to be the most I can do ...

Am I missing something about the ListViewItem.Tag Property??

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms - just updated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tag` property takes any object of type `object`, so any class that is inherited from object can be stored within it. So if you had an object like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLines { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeneric { get; set; }
}
```

You can assign your object to the tag field, like so:

```
var myobj = new MyItem();
myobj.Type = "Type 1";
myListView.Items[1].Tag = myobj;
```

And retrieve the object like so:

```
var myobj = (MyItem)myListView.Items[1].Tag;
var type = myobj.Type;
```

Only after you cast to `MyItem` can you access your custom properties. Otherwise you'll only get the `object` properties and methods, one of which is `.ToString()`.

Comment: so I can't just access the properties directly but have to dig them back out into an object in order to test...?  Would I be better off just inheriting and making my own custom ListViewItem?